# Parse json structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Im using ajax to query a json api. It gives me a Tree like structure, which I'd like to visualize. A sample response looks like

```
{
  "nicos": {
    "_lastconfig_": {
      "poller": {
        "alwayspoll": [], 
        "blacklist": [], 
        "neverpoll": [
          "detector"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    "poller": {
      "alwayspoll": [], 
      "autosetup": true, 
      "blacklist": [], 
      "description": "", 
      "loglevel": "info", 
      "lowlevel": false, 
      "neverpoll": [
        "detector"
      ], 
      "poll": []
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to parse this dynamically and visualize it as tables. A possible output could be

```
<h1>nicos</h1>
<h2>_last_config_</h2>
<table>
  <tr><td>alwayspoll</td><td>[]</td></tr>
  <tr><td>blacklist</td><td>[]</td></tr>
  <tr><td>neverpoll</td><td>[detector]</td></tr>
</table>
<h2>poller</h2>
<table>
  <tr><td>alwayspoll</td><td>[]</td></tr>
  <tr><td>autosetup</td><td>true</td></tr>
  <tr><td>blacklist</td><td>[]</td></tr>
  <tr><td>description</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>loglevel</td><td>info</td></tr>
  <tr><td>lowlevel</td><td>false</td></tr>
  <tr><td>neverpoll</td><td>[detector]</td></tr>
  <tr><td>poll</td><td>[]</td></tr>
</table>
```

Since I'm a complete novice in javascript I'm asking for some advice on how I could achive that. The ajax part is not the problem, but the parsing bothers me.

Comment: The AJAX part is not a problem, but this gives you headaches? Strange!

Comment: And it is good practice to use tbody/thead.

Comment: You should consider using `<ul>` though, as it is more of a list than tabular.

Comment: @PaulS. More like a `<dl>`

Comment: @P3trus Tables are deprecated and shouldn't be used if it can be helped. You can read more about `<dl>` and the new and awesome `HTML5` here: http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/

Comment: @DonovanGlover: **[Tables are not deprecated according to the W3C HTML5 spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/tabular-data.html#the-table-element)** The word _"deprecated"_ isn't even on that page.

Comment: @Cerbus My bad.. When I learned HTML, I was taught never to use tables. Maybe because of [Tableless web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design)? Either way, I don't see a good reason to use tables in modern-day development.

Comment: @DonovanGlover: Tables can be used just fine for tabular data. Thing small spreadsheets, stuff like that. That's what they're meant for. The problem with tables is that people were using them to build a site structure (header, sidebar, etc). That is where one shouldn't use tables.
Who taught you __never__ to use tables? I'd suggest smacking that person on the head to add some "gray" to his "black / white" view on the use of tables.

Answer (score 1):

**[Try this code](http://jsbin.com/ixojow/3/edit):**

```
function parse(obj){
    var s = '<table>';
    for(var k in obj){
        if(typeof obj[k] === 'object'){
            s += '<tr><td>'+k+'</td><td>'+parse(obj[k])+'</td></tr>\n';
        }else{
            s += '<tr><td>'+k+'</td><td>'+obj[k]+'</td></tr>\n';
        }
    }
    return s + '</table>\n';
}
parse(myJson);
```

Output:

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>nicos</td><td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>_lastconfig_</td><td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>poller</td><td>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>alwayspoll</td><td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>blacklist</td><td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td>0</td><td>X</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>1</td><td>Y</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>2</td><td>Z</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>neverpoll</td><td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td>0</td><td>detector</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>poller</td><td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>alwayspoll</td><td>
                        <table>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>autosetup</td><td>true</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>blacklist</td><td>
                        <table>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>description</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>loglevel</td><td>info</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>lowlevel</td><td>false</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>neverpoll</td><td>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>0</td><td>detector</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>poll</td><td>
                        <table>
                        </table>
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

(I added some variables to the arrays to show that those work, too)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing an Object to a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) ([`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/dl)) can be achieved with code such as this ([**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8zWg/)).

```
function objToDefnList(obj) { // returns a `<dl>` node (not appended to DOM Tree)
    var dl = document.createElement('dl'),
        dt, dd, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // title
            dt = document.createElement('dt');
            dt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
            dl.appendChild(dt);
            // defn.
            dd = document.createElement('dd');
            if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
                dd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[key].toString()));
            } else {
                dd.appendChild(objToDefnList(obj[key])); // recurse
            }
            dl.appendChild(dd);
        }
    }
    return dl; // done, return
}
```

It could very easily be modified to use any kind of list you want (e.g. `<ul>`, `<ol>`) or display more information (e.g. `typeof obj[key]`). You will probably need to style the elements, please see fiddle for an example of that, too.

Thanks to [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) for [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481076/parse-json-structure-with-javascript/14482177#comment-20177325) `<dl>` over `<ul>`.

Comment: For information on what a key is, it might be more complete to do something like `obj[key] && obj[key].constructor && obj[key].constructor.name || obj[key] === null && 'null' || obj[key] === undefined && 'undefined' || typeof obj[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON to an HTML Table is almost surely a wheel that has been invented:

https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table